# CKEditor creates instances on elements i don't want

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

I have a table, with simple contenteditable columns, where user need to input data. However, after i save data and reload the page, all contenteditable DIVs are gettings CKEditor instances which messes with my placeholder settings and other functionality. Also one interesting thing is, CKEditor instances spawns only on **contenteditable DIVs inside the table**, **inputs inside the table** or **contenteditable DIVs outside the table** are acting normal. Also there is one textarea outside the table, where CKEditor **is needed**.

I either need to **detect all CKEditor instances inside the table and destroy them**, or **prevent CKEditor instances to init inside my table**.

This is how i dynamically create new rows.

```
function addRow() {
                var mainRow = document.querySelector('#main-row');
                var tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');
                
                var newRow = document.createElement('tr');
                var rowIndex = tbody.children.length;
                newRow.classList.add('table-body-row');
                newRow.setAttribute('table-row-index', rowIndex);
                
                for(var i = 0; i < mainRow.children.length; i++) {
                    var newCol = document.createElement('td');
                    var newElement = createCol(tableColsConfig[i]);
                    
                    newCol.append(newElement);
                    newRow.append(newCol);
                }
                
                var iconDelete = newRow.children[mainRow.children.length - 1];
                iconDelete.innerHTML = '<i class="table-icon fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                iconDelete.classList.add('table-delete-box');
                iconDelete.classList.add('icon-container');
                iconDelete.setAttribute('table-row-index', rowIndex);
                iconDelete.setAttribute('onclick', 'deleteRow(this)');
                tbody.append(newRow);
                
                if(tbody.children.length === maxRows) {
                    addRowButton.classList.add('table-icon-disabled');
                }
            }
```

And this is function for dynamically create newCol:

```
function createCol(colConfig) {
                var element;
                var type;
                
                if(!colConfig || !colConfig.type) {
                    type = '';
                } else {
                    type = colConfig.type;
                }
                
                if(type === 'select') {
                    element = document.createElement('select');
                    element.classList.add('table-col-select');
                    
                    for(var j = 0; j < colConfig.options.length; j++) {
                        var current = colConfig.options[j];
                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.setAttribute('label', current.label);
                        option.setAttribute('value', current.value);
                        element.append(option);                         
                    }
                } else if(type === 'date') {
                    element = document.createElement('input');
                    element.classList.add('dateBlock');
                    element.classList.add('table-col-date');
                    
                    $(element).datetimepicker({
                        //defaultDate: new Date(),
                        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
                        pickTime: false, 
                        icons: {
                            time: "fa fa-clock-o", 
                            date: "fa fa-calendar", 
                            up: "fa fa-arrow-up", 
                            down: "fa fa-arrow-down" 
                        } 
                    });
                    $(element).on('dp.change', function(e) {
                        handleTableInput(e);
                    });
                } else if(type === 'number') {
                    element = document.createElement('div');
                    element.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
                    element.classList.add('table-col-text');
                    
                    $(element).keypress(function(e) {
                        if (isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) e.preventDefault();
                    });
                } else if(type === 'text') {
                    element = document.createElement('div');
                    element.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
                    element.classList.add('table-col-text');
                } else {
                    return;
                }
                
                //Привязка классов(если они заданы в конфиг массиве)
                if(colConfig.customClass) {
                    var classArr = colConfig.customClass;
                    
                    for(var i = 0; i < classArr.length; i++) {
                        element.classList.add(classArr[i]);
                    }
                }
                
                //Привязка коллбека(если он задан в конфиг массиве)
                if(colConfig.callback && colConfig.callbackType) {
                    var callbackFunc = colConfig.callback;
                    var callbackType = colConfig.callbackType;
                    element.setAttribute('on' + callbackType, callbackFunc  + '(event)');
                    if(colConfig.triggerImmediately) {
                        var customEvent = new Event(callbackType);
                        //customEvent.target = element;
                        //window[callbackFunc](customEvent);
                        element.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
                    }
                }
                
                //Привязка аттрибута(если он задан в конфиг массиве)
                if(colConfig.attr) {
                    var attrs = Object.entries(colConfig.attr);
                    for(var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
                        var attrName = attrs[i][0];
                        var attrValue = attrs[i][1];
                        element.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue);
                    }
                }
                
                element.addEventListener('change', function() {
                    handleTableInput(event)
                });
                
                element.addEventListener('input', function() {
                    handleTableInput(event)
                });
                
                element.setAttribute('inputId', colConfig.inputId);
                
                return element;
            }
```